# Checking the top bits of an i64 Value in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am going to keep this short and to the point, but if further clarifications are needed please let me know.

I have an i64 Value that I want to check the top bits of if they are zeros or not. If they are zeros, I would do something, if they are not, I would do something else. How do I instrument the IR to allow this to happen at runtime?

One thing I found is that LLVM has an intrinsic "llvm.ctlz" that counts the leading zeros and puts them in an i64 Value, but how do I use its return value to do the checking? Or how do I instrument so the checking happens at runtime?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how many top bits, so I'll do an example with the top 32 bits. Given `i64 %x`, I'd check it with `%result = icmp uge i64 %x, i64 4294967296` because 4294967296 is 2^32 and that is the first value which has a 1 bit in the top 32-bits. If you want to check the top two bits to be zero, use 2^62 (4611686018427387904) instead.

In order to do two different things based on the value of `%result` in general you'll want to branch on it. `BasicBlock` has a method `splitBasicBlock` that takes an instruction to split at. Use that to split your block into a before and after. Create new blocks for the true side an false side, add a branch on your result to your new blocks, `br i1 %result, label %cond_true, label %cond_false`. Make sure those two new blocks branch back to the after block.

Depending on what you want to do, you may not need an entire block, for instance if you're only calculating a value and not doing any side-effecting operations you might be able to use a `select` instruction instead of a branch and separate blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is interesting and didn't think about it before. What I was trying to do was to cast to ConstantInt and then use APInt to do arithmetic. But that wasn't working, not sure why. What I exactly want to do is to check if the top 15 bits are zeros or not. Would that be 2^15 = 32768?


Also, do you know if this impact the performance of the program much if I add this check frequently? I imagine yes, since there would be constant branch checking, right, like adding an if statement?

Comment: Was the value a compile-time constant? As opposed to an instruction or argument? If not, it's not a ConstantInt, you may not cast it to one and that would be why it wasn't working. For top 15 bits of 64-bit value, check whether it's greater or equal to than 2^(64-15), the unsigned-lowest value where the first 15 bits are not clear. Yes, adding it at run time would be as expensive as an if-statement. You may run the LLVM optimization passes afterwards to try to remove the branch, fold the branch away and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your answer is the right way to go and I have made progress. However, I run into an issue with inserting the PHINode. I am getting a PHINode that has itself, like this: 

%32 = phi i32 ()* [ %32, %22 ], [ %30, %28 ], !dbg !58

I am getting an error "Instruction does not dominate all uses" and I think this might be the reason. I am inserting the values correctly with addIncoming. What do you think is a possible solution?

Comment: Is `i32 ()*` the correct type (a pointer to function that takes no arguments and returns an `i32`? (Is that the type of `%32` and `%30`? Compare the `llvm::Type*`s, they must be the exact same pointer.) Also, PHINodes must be at the top of their basic block with no non-phi instructions before them.

Comment: There's one other thing, a PHINode must have one 'incoming' per branch that leads to the basic block. You have `%32 = phi i32 ()* [ %32,` meaning that sometimes the phi nodes is equal to itself. That can only be valid if this block ends with a branch back to itself. (However, this should cause a different error message, `PHINode should have one entry for each predecessor of its parent basic block!`.)